# Parameterised Enviroments in Lyx

Tags: lyx, environments, lyx-layouts

Ok,
I have a set of structured data that I want to format consistently.
In this case a set of spells for a role-playing game.
Now in Latex I vaguely remember I could do something using `\DeclareDocumentEnvironment` but it's been a while and I want to do it in LyX.

So I want my final document to look like:

### Fireball

**Casting Cost:** 2CP
**Casting Action:** Instant 
**Range:** Short 
Deals 2d12 damage to target

### Chain Lightning

**Casting Cost:** 1CP per target
**Casting Action:** Instant 
**Range:** Medium 
Chain lightning strikes through targets. 
All targets must be within Short distance from each other. 
Each target takes 1d6 damage

How do I go about setting something like this up?
I want to achieve constant look and formatting throughout my document.
I need a environment that takes multiple parameters.

I've really only used the more basic functions of Lyx before, like macro's for typing math (though I have used these functions alot_

Comment: New solution using LyX 2.1: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114591/lyx-style-for-command-with-multiple-arguments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My result using LyX first:

[image]

**Step 1: Creating an environment (or command) with parameters in LaTeX**

LyX is kind of a wrapper for LaTeX. So one needs to write the environment (or command) in LaTeX and should test it with a short LaTeX document. Exception: you are a LaTeX expert writing error-free LaTeX with perfect text layout. ;-)

There are **restrictions** on a LaTeX environment (or command) such that it can be *easily* mapped to a LyX style.

- Only one parameter which is optional is allowed for the LaTeX environment.
- Only two parameters with one of them optional are allowed for the LaTeX command.

Hence, in your case I would create a style (e.g. "MyTitle") for the title and one style for each detail. The last lines can be just plain text since no special format seems to be required.

**Step 2: Creating a style in LyX**

There must be a LyX style for each used environment (or command). These style definitions go into a `.module`-file. It should be placed in the `layout` folder of the lyx-tree in your home directory. LyX needs to be noticed about the new module. That is done by running `Reconfigure` of the LyX menu `Tools` and restarting LyX. Finally, for your document, under menu Document - Settings... - Modules add the new module (in the example "MyModule"). Now the new styles (e.g. "MyTitle") can be selected similar to "Section" or "Itemize".

Note: If an optional parameter is allowed for a LaTeX environment (or command) then it is denoted as "short title" in LyX. (That might come from the fact that a section heading can have optional parameter and its purpose is the short title). Furthermore, LyX maps it to the first LaTeX argument `#1`. Normal text is mapped to `#2`.

If no optional parameter is allowed, then LyX maps normal text to `#1`.

The folder `lyx/layout` of the LyX installation is a wealth of examples for definitions of styles, modules, and layouts. And the [LyX section](http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/lyx/lyx_latex_tex.htm#_LyX) of "LyX, LaTeX and TeX" by Steve Litt might be worth reading.

---

Here is the LaTeX document for Step 1:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newcommand{\mytitle}[1]{\bigskip\noindent\textbf{\large #1}\par\medskip}
\newcommand{\budget}[2][Dollar~]{\noindent\textbf{Budget:} #1#2\par}
\begin{document}
\mytitle{A Beautiful Mind}\budget[\$]{58 million}
This movie is about John Nash.........
\end{document}
```

The module file `MyModule.module` for Step 2.

```
#\DeclareLyXModule{MyModule}
#DescriptionBegin
#Defines some styles for movies.....
#DescriptionEnd
#Author: me

Format 35

Style MyTitle
    Category              MyModule
    Margin                Static
    LatexType             Command
    LatexName             mytitle
    NextNoIndent          1
    TopSep                1.3
    BottomSep             0.7
    Align                 Block
    Font
      Series              Bold
      Size                Larger
    EndFont
    OptionalArgs          0
    Preamble
      \newcommand{\mytitle}[1]{\bigskip\noindent\textbf{\large #1}\par\medskip}
    EndPreamble
End

Style Budget
    Category              MyModule
    LatexType             Command
    Margin                First_Dynamic
    LatexName             budget
    LabelType             Static
    LabelString           "Budget:"
    NextNoIndent          1
    LabelSep              xx
    ParIndent             MMM
    ParSkip               0.4
    ItemSep               0.2
    TopSep                0.7
    BottomSep             0.7
    ParSep                0.3
    Align                 Block
    AlignPossible         Left
    OptionalArgs          1
    LabelFont
      Shape               Up
      Series              Bold
    EndFont
    Preamble
      \newcommand{\budget}[2][Dollar~]{\noindent\textbf{Budget:} #1#2\par}
    EndPreamble
End
```

And the LyX document to generate the above image:

```
#LyX 2.0 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 413
\begin_document
\begin_header
\textclass article
\use_default_options true
\begin_modules
MyModule
\end_modules
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman default
\font_sans default
\font_typewriter default
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100
\font_tt_scale 100

\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize 12
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_amsmath 1
\use_esint 1
\use_mhchem 1
\use_mathdots 1
\cite_engine basic
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation 0pt
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout MyTitle
A Beautiful Mind
\end_layout

\begin_layout Budget
\begin_inset Argument
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
$
\end_layout

\end_inset

58 million
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
This movie is about John Nash.........

\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```