# Write a dictionary with LyX

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

How to make a dictionary with LyX ?
I found [this page](http://www.mengensatz.de/blog/?p=69) about this in LaTeX. The `\newenvironment` and `\newcommand` i put in Preamble or inside the text?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384) Please consider adding more detail including a [Minimum Working Example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/19384) to your post. That might help others to provide solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\newenvironment` and `\newcommand` have to go into the preamble "Document > Settings ... > LaTeX Preamble".

Note that they will not automatically create new styles. Unfortunately, you have to write LyX styles yourself. (For more details, see "Help > Customization" in LyX, and an example is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94812/24449).)

Alternatively, you could use "TeX code" / ERT (Ctrl-L) and write LaTeX directly, but then there is not much gain in using LyX. Or - if the dictionary is only a part of your document - you can include LaTeX code via "Insert > File > Child Document" using "Include Type: Input".