# How to do \hrulefill in LyX without a TeX inset

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lyx

A very similar, but significantly different question is [LyX command(s) to insert WYSIWYG horizontal line, for keyboard shortcut](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/208510/17868).

I'm trying to achieve the effect of `\hrulefill` in LyX, without resorting to an ERT (TeX code inset).

The example is the following:

```
Name and section:\enspace\hrulefill
```

All of the Width: options for Insert>Formatting>Horizontal Rule don't seem to achieve the same effect as `\hrulefill`, since they require a % of, or some fixed width, and aren't as dynamic. Is there some way to achieve this using the LyX interface?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert ▷ Formatting ▷ Horizontal space.

Spacing: horizontal fill

Fill pattern: __________

Comment: This truly generates the LaTeX code for `\hrulefill`. However, the feedback in the document is not so clear (I just see a vertical bar). If I add a character after, LyX will draw the underline all the way to the right margin (where my character also is). Is there a way to make it more obvious in the GUI without adding that character? Perhaps this is a LyX bug?

Answer (score 2):

You can add a Custom Inset by adding to your Document > Settings... > Local Layout

```
Format 49
InsetLayout "Flex:HRuleFill"
    LyXType          Custom
    LabelString      HRuleFill
    LatexType        Command
    LatexName        hrulefill
    Decoration       classic
    LabelFont        
        Color        blue
        Size         Small
    EndFont
    ResetsFont true
End
```

This should add an `HRuleFill` inset:

[image]

It's similar in nature to an ERT in my opinion.

Comment: Is there a way to have an inset that is either "closed" by default or doesn't allow content? Non-technical users could think they should type something into the inset. Perhaps by mapping a shortcut? I realize this wasn't part of my initial question.