# Writing custom.module file for LyX

Tags: errors, lyx, documentclass-writing, lyx-layouts, modules

## MWE:

This is for a custom.module file that should be accessed using the top-left drop down menu in LyX:

```
#\DeclareLyXModule{custom}
#DescriptionBegin
#Legal Format
#DescriptionEnd
#Author: Jalep

Format 63

Style Title
    Category              Custom
    Margin                Static
    LatexType             Command
    LatexName             title
    OptionalArgs          0
    Preamble
     \newcommand\MEETtitle{\large[1] { \noindent \LARGE \bf \begin{center} #1 \end{center}\rm } \vskip.1in \rm\normalsize } 
     \let\title\MEETtitle
     \renewcommand\maketitle{\vskip0pt} 
    EndPreamble
End
```

## Goal:

I'm trying to use this module file to allow a user in LyX to access commands created in my custom.cls file without having to type the TeX code in their LyX file i.e. using the top-left drop down menu. I can't find documentation really on how to format the module file, but I have based my MWE off this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/94555/parameterised-enviroments-in-lyx).

## More context:

The code between Preamble and EndPreamble is straight from the commands used in my custom.cls file. As done in the post I reference above.

## Issue:

LyX does not respond well to what I've written in this file: "Error reading custom module".

Comment: Hi, welcome. Try removing the line with `Format 63`.

Comment: Wow that worked! Like magic. Thank you Torbjørn and thanks for a very happy and successful welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was in the line with `Format 63`. After removing, this worked successfully.

## MWE:

```
#\DeclareLyXModule{custom}
#DescriptionBegin
#Legal Format
#DescriptionEnd
#Author: Jalep

Style Title
    Category              Custom
    Margin                Static
    LatexType             Command
    LatexName             title
    OptionalArgs          0
    Preamble
     \newcommand\MEETtitle{\large[1] { \noindent \LARGE \bf \begin{center} #1 \end{center}\rm } \vskip.1in \rm\normalsize } 
     \let\title\MEETtitle
     \renewcommand\maketitle{\vskip0pt} 
    EndPreamble
End
```